# Check that array of objects has all required keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this :

```
var field_arr = [{name:name},{email:email},{tel:tel}];
```

How to get the value of name, email or tel (property key) ? I want to use a loop to prompt user what is missing. For example, if user missed tel, there will be an alert saying `tel is missing`.

Comment: Could you not use a single object? Then it would be simple to loop through `Object.keys` once.

Comment: Assuming this is for a form, I'd definitely use the `required` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t think you need it to be an array. Just loop over all the properties of your JSON object.

```
 var obj = {
   name: "name",
   email: "",
   tel: "tel"
 };
 $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
   if (value == "") {
     console.log(key + ": " + value);
   }

 });
```

Comment: in pure js without $.each I used `for(key in obj)` instead.

Comment: Don't use `for(key in obj)`, especially without `.hasOwnProperty` guard. Use `Object.keys(obj)` instead.

Comment: If `obj` doesn't have some key at all like`var obj = {name: "name",tel: "tel" };` it won't log. There is no validation against anything and just checking if `obj` has any empty values. Check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to :

- turn your field_arr object into a key=>value type object
- then loop on your required list to check that each item is a key in that object :

Code :

```
var arr = {};
for(var i=0; i<field_arr.length; i++){
   var key = Object.keys(field_arr[i])[0];
   arr[key] = field_arr[i][key];
}

// At this point you have a key => value type array in "arr"

var required_list = ["name", "email", "tel"];
for(var i=0; i<required_list.length; i++){
  var item = required_list[i];
  if(! item in arr) {
     alert(item+" is missing");
  }
}
```

If you want to use forEach instead of a for loop :

```
var arr = {};
field_arr.forEach(function(obj){
      var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
      arr[key] = obj[key];
   });
}

// At this point you have a key => value type array in "arr"

var required_list = ["name", "email", "tel"];
required_list.forEach(function(item){
   if(! item in arr)
      alert(item+" is missing");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing those values from some fields with jQuery or something else. you can do something like :

```
var field_arr = [{name:"name"},{email:""},{tel:"lol"}];
jQuery.each(field_arr,function(obj){
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj[i].trim() === "") {
                 console.log(i + " is missing");
            }
        } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `filed_arr` is user input and you can't change the form of it and you want to compare it with `required` fields

```js
var field_arr = [{name:'abc'},{email:'xyz'}];

var required = ['name', 'email' , 'tel'];

var inputKeys = field_arr.reduce(function(prev,next){
  return prev.concat(Object.keys(next));
},[]);

document.write('<pre>inputKeys => ' +inputKeys+'</pre>');

var missingKeys = required.filter(function(key){
  return inputKeys.indexOf(key) == -1;
});

document.write('<pre>missingKeys => ' +missingKeys+'</pre');

alert('You are missing '+missingKeys);
```